# Descale: Vinegar vs citric acid and temperature

Tags: reaction-mechanism

The core of my question: What is the best temperature to descale with vinegar / citric acid?

I often read to use vinegar essence with 25% acidity, dilute it with water and then let it soak. Sometimes you're supposed to use warm, sometimes cold, and sometimes boiling water. 
How does the effectiveness depend on the temperature?

The same question I have for citric acid. If the temperature is too high (so I have read), you 're instead making calcium citrate (which is supposed to be harder). But what is too high? Why heat the solution at all?

Comment: Clarify your question please. What is the object made or what do you want to descale?

Comment: The temperature has only one effect : it decreases the duration of the operation. That's all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Higher temperature has several effects:

1. The rate of chemical reactions increases empirically and typically  2-4 times by every increase be 10° C
2. Heating toward boiling or intensive gasing turbulently mixes solution, what brings fresh solution to limescale.
3. Faster diffusion in hot solution due lower viscosity and higher ion/molecule mobility.

I never had problems with secondary precipitates with vinegar or citric acid, but I did have precipitated crystals in case of tartaric acid I had once handy.

I do not have data about temperature dependency of calcium citrate solubility, but I guess it may be rather that at high temperature one easier gets to higher concentrations.

What is essential is the $\mathrm{pH}$. With the higher ratio citric acid vs scale, there would be lower final $\mathrm{pH}$. Then the lower concentration of citrate anion would make calcium citrate precipitation less probable.